# concatenate characters of arr to the empty string one by one

Tags: c, string

I have an empty string *char prefix[100]=""* and another string of characters like *char arr[]={a,b}*.

My task is to concatenate characters of arr to the empty string prefix one by one.

I have tried the following but it is showing a warning as:

**initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]**

My Code:

```
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        char *current=str[i];
        strcat(prefix,current);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str[i]` needs to have a `&` in front like `&str[i]`.

Answer (score 3):

macduff's answer is correct, but I suggest using [`strncat()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/) instead of looping like you are as it's a standard library function and there's no reason not to use it to simplify your code. Usage:

```
strncat(prefix, arr, len);
```

Answer (score 0):

`strcat()` expects both its arguments to be null-terminated strings. This is not the case with your `current` argument, as you are simply passing the address of a single character. `strncat()` could be used to avoid that, but that would not accomplish your task of "concatenate characters of arr to the empty string prefix one by one". You probably need to:

1. find the end of your current `prefix` string, which is where you will append
2. loop over the characters in your `arr[]` array, placing each character in its proper place, and
3. make sure you correctly terminate the final result

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char prefix[100] = "";
    char arr[] = {'a', 'b'};
    //concatenate one by one
    //case 1
    int i, len = 2;
    int offset = 0;
    for(i=0;i<len;++i){
        offset += sprintf(prefix + offset, "%c", arr[i]);
        printf("DEBUG1:%s\n", prefix);
    }
    //case 2
    *prefix = '\0';
    char *str[] = {"a", "b"};
    for(i=0;i<len;++i){
        strcat(prefix, str[i]);//strcat is expecting a sequence that ends with '\0'
        printf("DEBUG2:%s\n", prefix);
    }

    return 0;
}
```